# how to send optional parameters to a "webservice" in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

i have a web service with signature :

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public Box FetchBox(string boxId, string p1, string p2, string p3 )
```

i call this web service by a jquery ajax :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/WS/Ajaxify.asmx/FetchBox",
  data: "{ 'boxId': '" + boxId + "' }",
  dataType: "json",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

i want to call FetchBox one time only with p1, later with p2 but not p1 and so on.

in many situations i need to call FetchBox method with any of p1 or p2 or p3 or ... 
parameter. i dont like to send all parameters because the system is plugin based and plugins do not know about others parameters.

optional parameter in c#4 does not working for a web service.

also params string[] parameters is not suitable here because i need to know the parameter name.

Comment: Why do you need to know the parameter name? What does p1, p2, or p3 mean?

Comment: i need to know the parameter name and its value to make a decision.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question - what logic is behind this?

Comment: Dude - you can't get more flexible than JSON.  SOAP web services are pretty much about fixed methods with fixed arguments.  REST services using JSON return types are inherently flexible: you just parse whatever you get.  This might not be the best example .. but maybe it'll give you a general sense of what's possible:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674188.aspx

Comment: there is a class with many default values. each plugin can ajaxly construct the class. i want only send desired parameters not all of them. this is easy in c# bot not in a web service :(

Comment: there is a simple solution: send parameters in querystring. but i am worry about query string limitations. any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot send optional parameters to a SOAP web service. The SOAP protocol has no concept of optional parameters.

Also, you should not be using ASMX services at all. That's a legacy technology that shouldn't be used for new development. WCF should be used instead.